# Casting between sockaddr and sockaddr_in6

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming

I've been reading Beej's Guide to Network Programming and in one of his examples, he casts a pointer to `struct sockaddr` to a `struct sockaddr_in6` pointer like shown below.

```
    void *addr;
    char *ipver;

    // get the pointer to the address itself,
    // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
    if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
        ipver = "IPv4";
    } else { // IPv6
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
        ipver = "IPv6";
    }
```

How is this possible, since the sizes of the structs are different?

Comment: The size doesn't matter, since you're just casting a pointer.

Comment: But you wrote he casts the pointers, not the structs.

Comment: My question is how he is able to access `sin6_addr` if `p->ai_addr` is a `struct sockaddr`

Comment: `ai_addr` IS NOT an actual `sockaddr`.  It is a **pointer** that is *typed* as `sockaddr*` (so it can be passed as-is to `bind()` and `connect()`), but the memory actually being pointed at is not a plain `sockaddr` itself, it is actually a derivative of `sockaddr` based on the reported `ai_family` (`sockaddr_in` for `AF_INET`, `sockaddr_in6` for `AF_INET6`). The `ai_addrlen` reports the actual size of the memory block being pointed at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ai_family` and `ai_addr` are fields of the `addrinfo` struct, so presumably the code you are quoting had called `getaddrinfo()` beforehand.

The result of `getaddrinfo()` is a NULL-terminated linked list of `addrinfo` structs, where the `addrinfo::ai_addr` field is a pointer to an allocated memory block that is of sufficient size to hold a socket address of the reported `addrinfo::ai_family` type.  The size of the address is reported in the `addrinfo::ai_addrlen` field.

For `AF_INET`, the `addrinfo::ai_addr` field is pointing at a memory block containing a `sockaddr_in` struct.

For `AF_INET6`, the `addrinfo::ai_addr` field is pointing at a memory block containing a `sockaddr_in6` struct.

That is why the type-casts work.

The `addrinfo::ai_addr` field is declared as `struct sockaddr*` so it can be passed as-is to the `addr` parameter of the `bind()` and `connect()` functions without type-casting. The `addrinfo::ai_addrlen` field can be passed as-is to their `addrlen` parameter.

Comment: So is `struct sockaddr` essentially a dummy data type used for legacy purposes since its fields are never used (besides `sa_family`)? Also, where is `ai_addrlen`? I can't seem to find it in any of the structs.

Comment: Essentially, yes.  It is a kind of poor-man's polymorphism for structs.  Over time, multiple `sockaddr_...` structs have been defined: `sockaddr_in` (what used to be `sockaddr` in the very beginning), `sockaddr_in6`, `sockaddr_un`, `sockaddr_bth`, etc. Each struct starts with a common `family` field, but otherwise they differ in overall size and content. Socket functions that support multiple address types operate on `sockaddr*` pointers and use the `family` field to differentiate.  `ai_addrlen` is a field of the `addrinfo` struct output from `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I totally missed that `addrinfo` had the `ai_addrlen` field which explains how `getaddrinfo()` knows the size of the struct.

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` knows the sizes of the structs because it is the one doing the memory allocation to begin with, based on the IP addresses it receives from its internal lookups.  It fills `ai_addrlen` on output to report the sizes to the caller.